# Non-nullable instance field 'arCoreController' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, dart-null-safety

Good day! I am new to Flutter but I was trapped in the problem to make an AR app

I have almost been frustrated all day because of these problems...

Dart Analysis keeps saying this below...

Non-nullable instance field ['Ar_controller'] must be initialized in flutter. My whole day wasted due to this and tomorrow is my presentation. Please help me out as soon as possible

really appreciate it in advance.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter_auth_ui/armodelselect.dart';
import 'package:arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:network_image_to_byte/network_image_to_byte.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector;

import 'armodelselect.dart';

class arviewpage extends StatefulWidget {
  objmodel modeldes;
  arviewpage(this.modeldes);
  @override
  _arviewpageState createState() => _arviewpageState(this.modeldes);
}

class _arviewpageState extends State<arviewpage> {
  _arviewpageState(this.modeldes);
  void initstate(){
    super.initState();
  }
  List<double> cubesize;
  objmodel modeldes;
  ArCoreController arCoreController;
  Uint8List byteImage,byteImage1;

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  const  Text('Xperience'),
        ),
        body:  ArCoreView(
          onArCoreViewCreated: _onArCoreViewCreated,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //functions::::::::::::::::::

  void  _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) {
    arCoreController = controller;
    if(modeldes.type=='sphere'){
      _addsphere();
    }
    else if(modeldes.type=="sphere2"){
      _addmoonearth();
    }
    else if(modeldes.type=='cube'){
      _addCube();
    }
  }

  //convert image to byteimage
  Future<Uint8List> _networkImageToByte(String imageaddress,String imageaddress1) async {
    byteImage = await networkImageToByte(imageaddress);
    if(imageaddress1!="0"){
      byteImage1=await networkImageToByte(imageaddress1);
    }
    return byteImage;
  }

  //convert cube size to double
  List<String> convertStringtodoublearr(String size){
    var cubesize=size.split(",");
    for(int i=0;i<cubesize.length;i++){
      this.cubesize[i]=double.parse(cubesize[i]);
    }
    return cubesize;
  }


  //sphere ar model implementation
  Future _addsphere() async {
    await _networkImageToByte(modeldes.img_url,modeldes.explain);

    //description ar model:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    final material = ArCoreMaterial(
      metallic: 1,
      color: Colors.blue,
      //metallic: 1.0,
      textureBytes: byteImage1,
    );
    final cube = ArCoreCube(
        materials: [material],
        size: vector.Vector3(0.5,0.2,0.1)
    );
    final node = ArCoreNode(
      shape: cube,
      position: vector.Vector3(0,-0.4,0.5),
    );

    //sphere texture model ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    final eamaterial = ArCoreMaterial(
      metallic: 1,
      color: Colors.blue,
      textureBytes: byteImage,
    );
    final sphere = ArCoreSphere(
      materials: [eamaterial],
      radius: double.parse(modeldes.size[0]),
    );
    final eanode = ArCoreNode(
      shape: sphere,
      position: vector.Vector3(0,0,-1),
      children: modeldes.explain=="0"?[]:[node],
    );
    arCoreController.addArCoreNode(eanode);
  }


  //cube ar model implementation
  Future _addCube() async{
    await _networkImageToByte(modeldes.img_url,modeldes.explain);

    //description ar model::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    final material = ArCoreMaterial(
      metallic: 1,
      color: Colors.blue,
      //metallic: 1.0,
      textureBytes: byteImage1,
    );
    final cube = ArCoreCube(
        materials: [material],
        size: vector.Vector3(0.5,0.2,0.1)
    );
    final node = ArCoreNode(
      shape: cube,
      position: vector.Vector3(0,-0.4,0.5),
    );

    //cube texture model ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;

    final cube_material = ArCoreMaterial(
      metallic: 1,
      color: Colors.blue,
      //metallic: 1.0,
      textureBytes: byteImage,
    );
    final cube_cube = ArCoreCube(
      materials: [cube_material],
      size: vector.Vector3(double.parse(modeldes.size[0]),double.parse(modeldes.size[1]),double.parse(modeldes.size[2])),
    );
    final cube_node = ArCoreNode(
      shape: cube_cube,
      children: modeldes.explain=="0"?[]:[node],
      position: vector.Vector3(0,0,-1),
    );
    arCoreController.addArCoreNode(cube_node);
  }



  Future _addmoonearth() async {
    await _networkImageToByte(modeldes.img_url,modeldes.explain);

    //description ar model:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    final material = ArCoreMaterial(
      metallic: 1,
      color: Colors.blue,
      //metallic: 1.0,
      textureBytes: byteImage1,
    );
    final moon = ArCoreSphere(
      materials: [material],
      radius: 0.05,
    );
    final node = ArCoreNode(
      shape: moon,
      position: vector.Vector3(0.2,0.3,0.5),
    );

    //sphere texture model ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    final eamaterial = ArCoreMaterial(
      metallic: 1,
      color: Colors.blue,
      textureBytes: byteImage,
    );
    final sphere = ArCoreSphere(
      materials: [eamaterial],
      radius: double.parse(modeldes.size[0]),
    );
    final eanode = ArCoreNode(
      shape: sphere,
      position: vector.Vector3(0,0,-1),
      children: modeldes.explain=="0"?[]:[node],
    );
    arCoreController.addArCoreNode(eanode);
  }




  @override
  void dispose() {
    arCoreController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If some variable is not initialized at definition,
you need to 'late' keyword.

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization

```
...

late ArCoreController arCoreController;

...
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that now while running the main.dart. It's saying.
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:camera
 - package:flutter_mobile_vision
 - package:arcore_flutter_plugin
 - package:network_image_to_byte

Comment: Your flutter environment supports Null-Safety. But 'flutter_mobile_vision' package not supports Null-Safety.<br>
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobile_vision/versions

Comment: Because the 'flutter_mobile_vision_2' pakcage supports Null-Safety, you'd better chagne package from 'flutter_mobile_vision' to 'flutter_mobile_vision_2'.

Comment: What about for these packages?


 - package:camera
 - package:arcore_flutter_plugin
 - package:network_image_to_byte

Comment: You can search pakcage at 'pub.dev' and check 'version' tab what version supports Null-Safety. Or https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-outdated using this, you can check version compatible.

Comment: sklite only has one version which doesn't support null safety. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your package name which requires null safety
2. Go to pub.dev, search for the package name.
3. Look for similar package with null safety tag.
4. Copy package name from pub.dev
5. Paste in your pubspec.yaml in place of old package name.
6. Click on download button if working in VS Code or type in the command

   flutter pub get

Comment: I did that and now it says  Undefined class 'ArCoreController'

Comment: I used ar_flutter_plugin for arcore_flutter_plugin package. As it supports null safety.

Comment: 1. Type in command prompt - flutter clean & then 2. Type in cmd prompt - flutter pub get